# montar uma expressão regular

Tags: javascript, html

gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês para montar uma expressão para verificar se existe mais de 3 barras dentro de uma url no javascript. exemplo: http://exemplo.com , esse ele não pega. http://exemplo.com/ola/, Esse ele pega. irei utilizar a expressão no método test();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exemplo de busca de, no mínimo, 3 barras:

```
var expr = /\/(.*\/){2,}/;

alert(expr.test('http://exemplo.com')); // exibe false
alert(expr.test('http://exemplo.com/ola/')); // exibe true
```

Esta expressão procura por um texto com 3 barras com qualquer número de caracteres entre cada uma elas (incluindo nenhum).

**Edição:** A expressão acima busca o texto mais extenso possível, iniciando com uma barra, terminando com uma barra e possuindo pelo menos 3 barras. Seguindo a filosofia no comentário de @mgibsonbr de melhor eficiência, que eu concordo, uma expressão mais restritiva com menor processamento, encontra somente as três primeiras barras com o menor número possível de caracteres entre elas seria:

```
var expr = /\/.*?\/.*?\//;
```

Como o autor da pergunta quer somente verificar, com expressão regular, se a condição é verdadeira, esta última expressão é mais apropriada mesmo.

Comment: Boa resposta. Eu colocaria o operador de repetição não- *greedy* por eficiência (ex.: `.*?`), mas funciona de uma forma ou de outra.

Answer (score 8):

Se queres verificar so se há ou não há então não precisas de regex. Podes usar o `split` que é mais rápido.

```
function tem3Barras(url){
    return url.split('/').length > 3;
}
```

Se não quiseres com tar com `//` então podes juntar duas linhas para verificar isso e separar essa parte.

```
function tem3Barras(url){
    var doubleBar = url.indexOf('//');
    if (doubleBar != -1) url = url.slice(doubleBar + 2);
    return url.split('/').length > 2;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6w0cx0n/

Answer (score 7):

Segue um exemplo:

```
var array = [
    'http://exemplo.com',
    'http://exemplo.com/ola',
    'http://exemplo.com/ola/',
    'www.exemplo.com/ola/mundo/javascript',
    'www.exemplo.com/ola/mundo/javascript/'
];

array.forEach(function (elm) {

    if (elm.match(new RegExp('\/', 'g')).length > 3) {
        console.dir('possui mais de 3 barras: ' + elm);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Aqui uma forma simples de fazer uma validação:

```
function checkBars(url) {
  if (url.indexOf('/') !== -1) {
     if (url.split('/').length > 3) {
        return true;      
     }
  }
return false;
}

if (checkBars('http://www.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91990/montar-uma-expressão-regular/92057')) {
  alert('possui mais de 3 barras');
} else {
  alert('possui menos de 3 barras');
}
```